# How to loop the <windows.h> system("color") command in order to make command prompt rapidly change its colors?

Tags: c, windows, cmd, colors, attributes

Just for fun, but nonetheless, the task is to make the cmd window automatically change its color without user input. Something like this could be done by using system("color"). I've tried looping it

`for(;;) {
system("color 1c");
system("color 3f");
}`

(and adding more "color" commands with different attributes in that loop), but apparently the colors don't change while in a loop. 
And the second question, how to turn the attributes into a variable, that constantly gets incremented, so that we wouldn't need to copy-paste a dozen of color commands with different attributes?
As for the second part the only idea I had was `system("color %d")`, but needless to say that won't even compile.

Comment: I replaced the **loops** tag with **windows** because the loop is stupid. Nothing will be furthered than setting the colours once. This isn't a "how-to" site. Please post the code you tried in the second part of the question.

Comment: There's nothing to post about the second part, using a format specifier (literally the only idea I had) for system("color %d") won't even compile. That's the whole premise of the question, using a variable instead of an attribute the latter which is to be input by the user. Needless to say, if there was any info about this when googling it, I wouldn't be asking this question here.

Comment: Yes there is: what you have tried. This is not a vague "how-to" site, but for specific problems with C code.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*. Please [read the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: It seems strange at the very least that something as comprehensive as "Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example" is required to give you an understanding of this very simple and trivial problem. 
Then again, I hope your ego is satisfied, you people downvote questions that can't be researched but welcome stuff like "difference between command prompt and cmd' - something that can be easily looked up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system()` receives a string, not a format. You can use `snprintf()` to write the string you want into a buffer, then giving that over to system.

Edit: tried it out, works as intended:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    srand(374); //doesnt need to be a proper seed, since just for fun
    char *buf = malloc(64); //should be enough
    loop:
    snprintf(buf, 64, "color %d%d", rand()%10, rand()%10);
    system(buf);
    goto loop;
    return 0;
}
```

And yes, i know that there is no free(), but its an infinite loop anyway. :^)
Also this solution ignores some colours, since it only writes 0-9 and not also A-F, but i guess we can ignore the light versions of some colours, as the intended effect is there anyway.

Comment: Many thanks, worked like a charm. Was a bit of a hassle to get it running on visual studio, but no problem on code blocks.

Comment: @OlegPlachkov if it solved your problem then accept the answer.